# Expression Engine: jQuery bind() only works on index

Tags: jquery, bind, live, expressionengine

I'm building a website on Expression Engine using jQuery for my javascript.

At first it looks as if everything works as it should. But as I navigate away from the front page (*index.php*) to a subpage (*index.php/site/services*) all my event handlers stop working. I know the javascript is executed on page load, and there are no errors in console.

I'm guessing the problem has to do with the `bind()` function, and I've tried substituting it with `live()` without success.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: ok press ctrl + r to force cache cleared, then look into the javascript, if it is really there and finally use absolute urls don't use relative urls.

Comment: Yup, the problem was a relative URL in an ajax function related to the event handlers.

Comment: lol people work in mysterious ways :)... but im guessing it's something you should know as a developer :), but as my teacher said once :) better ask a stupid question and learn from it, than be stupid for the rest of your life so don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok press ctrl + r to force cache cleared, then look into the javascript, if it is really there and finally use absolute urls don't use relative urls.